# Should I tell my manager that I may leave for a different reason?

Tags: software-industry, resignation

I work in a tech giant (top 100 by Forbes), I have been working there (part time, I am still a student) for 9 months and I submitted my notice as I have decided to start a  master's degree.

A week later, I was contacted by one of the big five (and my dream company) and asked me if I would like to interview for what I consider to be the dream job.
I asked how they contacted me and apparently my professor who works as a researcher submitted my name as a part of a shortlist.

I am willing to delay starting my MA to work this job, I am leaving the current job **before** interviewing for my dream company and I will receive the answer a month before the final withdrawal date from the MA program, should I tell my manager that there might be a possibility that I may not start MA but rather start to work for another company?

Comment: Either you submit a notice stating you will leave on date XX.XX or you don't. Never seen a notice saying "I might be leaving...".

Comment: I should rephrase, I have submitted a notice that I am leaving but haven't specified a date but rather a range.

Comment: You submit a date range to me and you will be out the door on the earliest date... I can then pay someone else...

Comment: @SolarMike not always, my old company was happy that I gave a long notice period which allowed me to train up my replacement

Comment: @Bee if you give me notice that you will leave between the 10th and 20th of the month then I will do your papers for the 10th as I made clear in my comment. If you provide 3 or 4 weeks notice to leave on the 29th then the 29th it is and that enables the training to occur...

Comment: @Solar I assumed the OP was a while out and was therefore going to let them know closer to the time. In general though I agree that you should just pick a date

Comment: What is big five?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see why you *need* to tell your boss why you're leaving at all.

It's not really any of their business why you want to leave - unless you *want* to tell them.

[[ I've not heard of anyone submitting a notice that they **might** be leaving before. You either **are** leaving, or you're **not**. ]]

Usually when you hand in your notice you negotiate the leaving date based on the notice period in your contract (sometimes shorter, sometimes longer, but there's usually a fixed date) and that is **final** unless it gets re-negotiated (and both parties agree).

The reason for leaving has no bearing on this (except to influence your own desire for a specific leaving date).

There's also nothing stopping you from saying how much you enjoyed working there, sorry to leave, etc whether true or not.

Answer (score 8):

There's no reason. Treat it like telling your boss "I'll be heading home now" but you stop to buy groceries.
The reason for your notice was to leave for MA. In the meantime you **just** got **offer** of **interview**. If all those 3 will come to fruition you will only be after interview. If they will not give you an offer you will still go with your plan of MA.
And you should stick to that.

Comment: I would however not lie if asked a question about their MA though. OP did nothing wrong, those things happen, so no need to lie or stress about it.